# Regex for Any English ASCII Character Including Special Characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to write a regex in php to match only any english characters, spaces, numbers and all special chars.

From this question
[Regex any ascii character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)

I tried this

```
preg_match("/[\x00-\x7F]+/", $str);
```

but it throws a warning

```
No ending delimiter '/' found
```

so, how to write this regex in php.

the alternative would be smth like [a-z\d\s] and also one by one consider all special chars, but is not there a way to do simpler ?

Thanks

Comment: @VedantTerkar: No, but it might be a good idea to use single quotes since in double-quoted strings, `\xnn` character escapes will be interpreted. I don't know PHP, but maybe it's getting thrown off by an ASCII NUL character inside a string?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a number of intricate solutions, but I would suggest this beautifully simple regex:

```
^[ -~]+$
```

It allows all printable characters in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

**In PHP:**

```
$regex = '%^[ -~]+$%';
if (preg_match($regex, $yourstring, $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
    } 
else { // no match...
     }
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The character class `[ -~]` matches all characters between the space and the tilde (all the printable characters in the ASCII table)
- The `+` quantifier means "match one or more of those"
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Added PHP code. I build this a while ago and have been using it, it works great, highly recommend it. :)

Comment: Didn't mean to imply you needed that code... Sounds like you're a pro. :) It's there more for a newbie who might read it a year from now, always nice to complete the answer. Btw when I built that regex some time ago I realized there are cool variations, for instance `[!-~]` for all printable chars minus the space.

Comment: come on bro !! :) no prob, I just commented, without any implications or smth. Sure, u r right, I am completely with u. That is cool stuff, tks for the additional info :)

Comment: I tried it as soon as I found out it worked, a warning poped up sayting u can accept in 6 mins, lemme try again ;)

Comment: +1 for the use of `[ -~]`, not very widely used range that is.

Comment: You're very much welcome @zx81 Glad to see another of the "good guys" on SO, *cheers!*

Comment: Great suggestion! There's a problem with the PHP code, though. You should either escape the `~` in the range or use another delimiter.

Comment: Works great. When i used it with textarea, new lines caused problems though. so i had to add space in the regex: /^[ -~\s]+$/

Answer (score 3):

PHP's regex comes with [a set of character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) you can reference, ascii being one of them

```
$test = "hello world 123 %#* 单 456";
preg_match_all("/[[:ascii:]]+/",$test,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: thanks for the asnwer, but this does not work, e.g. try `asdfas==адъфасдфас==asdfasd` with string, that contains Russian chars, does not work. @zx81's solution works fine. tks

Comment: @dav it seems to work for me `[0] => asdfas== [1] => ==asdfasd`, what is your expected result? http://ideone.com/giYFW1

Comment: this is interesting, in my localhost I tried exactly this code, just copy pasted `$test = 'asdfas==адъфасдфас==asdfasd';; preg_match_all("/[[:ascii:]]+/",$test,$matches); print_r($matches);die;` and I get this result `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => asdfas==адъфасдфас==asdfasd ) )`, but in http://phpfiddle.org/ it outputs this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => asdfas== [1] => ==asdfasd ) )` , did u try in fiddle or in localhost ? it looks like there is encoding problem in that fiddle. tks

Comment: @dav i tried it on localhost and got the same results as your and my fiddles